# How to create control that draws a table in panel

Tags: c#, winforms

I want create a control that draws a table in panel . My code is:

```
 public class PanelZ : System.Windows.Forms.Panel
{

    public static void Draw()
    {
        Panel p = new Panel();
        p.Width = 200;
        p.Height = 200;
        Graphics g = p.CreateGraphics();
        Pen mypen = new Pen(Brushes.Black, 1);
        Font myfont = new Font("tahoma", 10);
        int lines = 9;
        float x = 0;
        float y = 0;
        float xSpace = p.Width / lines;
        float yspace = p.Height / lines;
        for (int i = 0; i < lines + 1; i++)
        {
            g.DrawLine(mypen, x, y, x, p.Height);
            x += xSpace;
        }
        x = 0f;
        for (int i = 0; i < lines + 1; i++)
        {
            g.DrawLine(mypen, x, y, p.Width, y);
            y += yspace;
        }

    }
```

..but it dosen't draw a table; so what should I do?

Comment: a) define what you mean by a Table - a grid?  with lines? b) get rid of CreateGraphics and do your painting in the OnPaint method

Comment: _Graphics g = p.CreateGraphics();_ Almost always a mistake. For drawing use the OnPaint event!!

Comment: Can you use a `TableLayoutPanel` or a `GridView` or `ListView` with lines drawn?

Comment: Have you resolved your problems?

Comment: yes it is fixed, thank you

Answer (score 4):

This will work. But the numbers ought to be properties, as should the pen and then some.. Also: Properties ought to start with an uppercase letter.

```
 public class PanelZ : System.Windows.Forms.Panel
 {
    public PanelZ()                  // a constructor
    {
        Width = 200;
        Height = 200;
        DoubleBuffered = true;
        lines = 9;
    }

    public   int lines { get; set; }  // a property

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)  // the paint event
    {
        base.OnPaint(e);

        Graphics g = e.Graphics;
        Pen mypen = new Pen(Brushes.Black, 1);
        Font myfont = new Font("tahoma", 10);
        float x = 0;
        float y = 0;
        float xSpace = Width / lines;
        float yspace = Height / lines;
        for (int i = 0; i < lines + 1; i++)
        {
            g.DrawLine(mypen, x, y, x, Height);
            x += xSpace;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < lines + 1; i++)
        {
            g.DrawLine(mypen, 0, y, Width, y);
            y += yspace;
        }
    }
}
```

At work in VS:

[image]

Note that this only colors pixels. There is no useful grid there, just pixels with color.. So, if you actually want to use the Font you define you will have to calculate the coodordinates and the bounding boxes.